# UIViewPropertyAnimator not working as expected when using initialVelocity

Tags: ios, swift, animation, velocity, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am going to try to explain my problem with a simple example. I have a UIView with a top constraint and a height constraint. I attempt to animate an increase in the height constraint. Here are two ways of doing so.

```
    // case 1
    heightConstraint.constant += 100
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 25.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

    // case 2
    heightConstraint.constant += 100
    let timingParams = UISpringTimingParameters(dampingRatio: 0.8, initialVelocity: CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 25.0))
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.8, timingParameters: timingParams)
    animator.addAnimations {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    animator.startAnimation()
```

For case 1 the animation performs as expected. For case 2, however, the animation disregards the fixed top constraint that I set for my UIView. It first uses the initial velocity to perform a translation on the view, and after the speed has reached 0, it starts scaling the UIView relative to its center.

Could someone please tell me what am I missing?